# Python Split not working properly

Tags: python, arrays, unicode, split

I have the following code to read the lines in a file and split them with a delimiter specified. After split I have to write some specific fields into another file.

**Sample Data**:

```
Week49_A_60002000;Mar;FY14;Actual;Working;E_1000;PC_000000;4287.63
```

**Code**:

```
import os
import codecs
sfilename = "WEEK_RPT_1108" + os.extsep + "dat"
sfilepath = "Club" + "/" + sfilename
sbackupname = "Club" + "/" + sfilename + os.extsep + "bak"
try:
    os.unlink(sbackupname)
except OSError:
    pass

os.rename(sfilepath, sbackupname)

try:
    inputfile = codecs.open(sbackupname, "r", "utf-16-le")
    outputfile = codecs.open(sfilepath, "w", "utf-16-le")
    sdelimdatfile = ";"
    for line in inputfile:
        record = line.split(';')
        outputfile.write(record[1])
except IOError, err:
    pass
```

I can see that the 0th array position contains the whole line instead of the first record:

```
record[0] = Week49_A_60002000;Mar;FY14;Actual;Working;E_1000;PC_000000;4287.63
```

while on printing `record[1]`, it says array index out of range.
Need help as new to python.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works fine for me: the line splits on semicolons.

Comment: Are you sure the file encoding is really "utf-16-le"? Maybe it does not detect the semicolons because your encoding messes it up. Or try a unicode semicolon as separator (`u';'`). I'd also recommend using Python 3 which has easier unicode support. And you probably want to change `record = line.split(';')` to `record = line.split(sdelimdatfile )`.

Comment: what does `inputfile.read()[:500]` show?

Comment: That's weird and sounds like an exception being silently caught at a moment. But what Python version are you using? Version 2 and 3 act differently for byte and unicode strings...

Comment: @Byte Commander: 
I have tried with 
record = line.split(sdelimdatfile ).
its still the same.

Comment: @john1024
Not sure why it doesn't works for me.
I am using Jython to get this done.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta: I am using Jython 2.5.1
I have a compulsion to use this as the code is expected to run on an oracle tool which supports Jython 2.5.1

Comment: Ok, you use a Jython 2.5, so line should be an unicode string. Try to remove the `try... catch` that could mask an exception, add a `print repr(line)` before the `record = line.split(';')` and report what happens

Comment: @Serge Ballesta:  The output is : u'\u6557\u6b65\u3934\u415f\u365f\u3030\u3230\u3030\u3b30\u614d\u3b72\u5946\u3431\u413b\u7463\u6175\u3b6c\u6f57\u6b72\u6e69\u3b67\u5f45\u3031\u3030\u503b\u5f43\u3030\u3030\u3030\u343b\u3832\u2e37\u3336'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you comment saying that `print line` outputs `u'\u6557\u6b65\u3934\u415f\u365f\u3030\u3230\u3030\u3b30\u614d\u3b72\u5946\u3431‌​\u413b\u7463\u6175\u3b6c\u6f57\u6b72\u6e69\u3b67\u5f45\u3031\u3030\u503b\u5f43\u3‌​030\u3030\u3030\u343b\u3832\u2e37\u3336'`, I can explain what happens and how to fix it.

#### What happens:

you have a normal 8bits characters file, and the line you show is even in plain ASCII, but you try to decode it as if it were in UTF-16 little endian. So you wrongly combine every two bytes in a single 16 bits unicode character! If your system had been able to correctly display them and if you had directly print line instead of repr(line), you would have got `敗步㤴䅟㙟〰㈰〰㬰慍㭲奆㐱䄻瑣慵㭬潗歲湩㭧彅〱〰倻彃〰〰〰㐻㠲⸷㌶`. Of course, none of those unicode characters is the semicolon (`;` or `\x3b` of `\u003b`) so the line cannot be splitted on it.

But as you encode it back before writing `record[0]` you find the whole line in the new file, what let you believe erroneously that the problem is in the `split` function.

#### How to fix:

Just open the file normally, or use the correct encoding if it contains non ascii characters. But as you are using a version 2 of python, I would just do:

```
try:
    inputfile = open(sbackupname, "r")
    outputfile = open(sfilepath, "w")
    sdelimdatfile = ";"
    for line in inputfile:
        record = line.split(sdelimdatfile)
        outputfile.write(record[1])
except IOError, err:
    pass
```

If you really need to use the codecs module, for example if the file contains UTF8 or latin1 characters, you can replace the open part with:

```
encoding = "utf8"  # or "latin1" or whatever the actual encoding is...
inputfile = codecs.open(sbackupname, "r", encoding)
outputfile = codecs.open(sfilepath, "w", encoding)
```

Answer (score -1):

Then there is no index [1]:
Either skip the line with "continue" if len(record) < 1 or just not write to the file (like here)

```
    for line in inputfile:
            record = line.split(';')
            if len(record) >= 1:
                    outputfile.write(record[1])
```

Comment: The problem is that the string which appears to contain semicolons is not being split on the semicolons.

Comment: How can there be no record[1] if I am splitting a record: Week49_A_60002000;Mar;FY14;Actual;Working;E_1000;PC_000000;4287.63     
with a " ; " delimeter.
Ideally record[0] should be = Week49_A_60002000 and record[1] = Mar.
My issue is not the error but to parse the records and write the output in a file.

Comment: Hmmm, then I don't know as your program works fine on my testfile. Is line identical to record[0]?

Comment: Yes the line is identical to record[0]. Surprisingly both Line & Record[0] are exactly same. That is why I feel that there is some issue with Line.split

Comment: Surprisingly both Line & Record[0] are exactly same.